# Storybook Angular - Inject NgControl

Tags: angular, angular9, storybook, constructor-injection

I have the following Class :

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

constructor(
  @Optional()
  @Self()
  public ngControl: NgControl) {
    if (ngControl) {
      ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
}
```

And I would like to write a Story about it.

This is what I have tried, it's not working

```
export const test= () => ({
  moduleMetadata: {
    imports: [
      TestModule
    ],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: NgControl,
        useClass: class extends NgControl {
          control = new FormControl();
          viewToModelUpdate() {
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

**ngControl** is not injected, it is null.
How can I do it ?

I did this in my unit test :

```
class NgControlMock extends NgControl {
  readonly control: AbstractControl | null = new FormControl('');

  viewToModelUpdate(newValue: any): void {
  }
}

 beforeEach(() => {
    ngControlMock = new NgControlMock();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
      declarations: [TestComponent],
      providers: []
    })
      .overrideComponent(TestComponent, {
        set: {
          providers: [
            {
              provide: NgControl,
              useValue: ngControlMock
            }
          ]
        }
      })
      .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
```

But I don't know how to do something similar with Storybook

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://blog.web-worker.in/documenting-components-storybook-angular/

create a FormGroup and a FormControl in the Storybook.

Pass the parameter to the component.

Then Access the Control through the parameter, you can of course pass also the parameter name or just the control itself.
The validation then works in the storybook.

**Update:**
The ngControl gets injected when you wrap the template defined in the storybook with a form element and you have to export the ngForm directive (https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm), ("#f="ngForm"" is the important bit) into the template like so, also dont forget to add the ngControl provider into moduleMetadata in Storybook:

```
export const input = () => {
  return {
      component: GenericInputComponent,
      decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
          declarations: [GenericInputComponent],
             imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserModule, CommonModule, FormsModule],
        })
      ],
      template: `<form #f="ngForm">
                    <generic-input ngModel name="something">
                    </generic-input>
                 </form>`,
                  props: {
                        placeholder: "name",
                        isRequired: true,
                        errorMsg: "Please enter your name",
                        label: "User Name",
                      },
  }
}

constructor(@Self() public controlDir:NgControl){
  this.controlDir.valueAccessor = this;
}



ngOnInit() {
        const control = this.controlDir.control;
         const validators: ValidatorFn[] = control.validator ? [control.validator] : [];
        if (this.isRequired) {
          validators.push(Validators.required);
        }
        control.setValidators(validators);
        control.updateValueAndValidity();
      }
```